# How to select people that don't know anyone who takes workshops

Tags: sql, database

I have a few tables I want to iterate over. First table is **Persons**:

| id | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Laura Jansen | New York |
| 2 | Sana Vendi | Miami |
| 3 | Adam Smith | Boston |
| 4 | Mo Zora | Los Angeles |

Second one is **TakingWorkshop**. This is the workshop the people are taking, so `person_id` is the id of the one in Persons.

| id | person_id | workshop_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 4 | 26 |
| 19 | 2 | 27 |
| 18 | 3 | 28 |

Last table is **Knows**. The person id's are the same as the id's in Persons. So, PersonX knows PersonY.

| PersonX | PersonY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

So 1 is Laura, 2 is Sana and 3 is Adam. We can see that Adam doesn't know anyone. That means that Adam automatically also doesn't know anyone who takes workshops, because he doesn't even know anyone. However, in the table we see that Laura, 1, doesn't take workshops. So 4 and 2, Mo and Sana, know Laura, but she doesn't take any workshops so Mo and Sana don't know anyone who takes workshops.

I wrote some code for the people who don't know anyone taking workshops (in this database, it's Adam)
First I do a left join on the Person table and Knows table, on the id of persons and the id of personA of Knows. PersonA knows person B. This join gives me a table of people who know people, including the people who don't know anyone (those are null).

```
    SELECT distinct P.name, K.personA_id
    FROM Persons P LEFT JOIN Knows K
    ON P.id = K.personA_id
```

Now I want to see if personB_id is in the person_id of TakingWorkshop. This way you can see whether the known people are taking workshops or not. PersonB_id should NOT be in TakeingWorkshop, because that's how you filter out Laura. I did this like this:

```
    WHERE K.personB_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id
               FROM TakingWorkshop)
```

So my whole code looks like this

```
    SELECT distinct P.name, K.personA_id
    FROM   Persons P LEFT JOIN Knows K
        ON P.id = K.personA_id
    WHERE  K.personB_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id
               FROM   TakingWorkshop)
```

But I get no results when I do this and want to know what's going wrong

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Your description of the problem suggests `not exists`.  But not exists what?

This query gets everyone who is known and taking a workshop:

```
select . . .
from knows k join
     TakingWorkshop tw
     on k.personY = tw.person_id;
```

So, we can slip that into the query:

```
select p.*.
from persons p
where not exists (select 1
                  from knows k join
                       TakingWorkshop tw
                       on k.personY = tw.person_id
                  where k.personX = p.id 
                 );
```